# PostgreSql. Strange behavior of concatenation

Tags: postgresql, char, concatenation

Very short question. Can anyone say why this query

```
select LENGTH(' '::char || ' '::char), LENGTH(' '::text || ' '::char), LENGTH(' ' || ' '), LENGTH('a'::char || 'b'::char);
```

returns

```
0    1    2    2
```

Is space a *special* character witch don't concatenate with other strings?

Documentation says only this:

```
Unless otherwise noted, all of the functions listed below work
on all of these types, but be wary of potential effects of
automatic space-padding when using the character type.
```

Why I do this? Because i'm building string char by char in stored procedure, and when i try to concatenate varchar with char nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CHAR type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/datatype-character.html) is "fixed-length, blank padded". This means that if you store `"foobar"` into a `char(10)` field, Postgres actually stores `"foobar    "` (that's four trailing spaces, SO does not preserve adjacent whitespace). When you fetch back your value, any trailing whitespace is stripped out. The same happens with `' '::char` — its trailing whitespace is stripped, leaving only a zero-length string.

Comment: So i changed my type of my variable that contains currient char from char(1) to varchar(1) and everythign becomes fine. Thanks.